# Writing unit test for randomly generated values (How to use Assert.Egual() in this scenario)

Tags: c#, unit-testing

myDict dictionary values are generated based on a random generator.
At the end, the values of the this dictionary, and the values of the keypairlist should be equal.
(Actually, the Key-Value Pairs in both of them will be matched, I just used values but I can use pairs also, if needed)

But, since the order of the myDictionary changes everytime, I couldn't come up with a solution for `Assert.Equal()` function. Is there something I can do about this?

for example,

list of pairs can be like: (1,2)
(3,4)
(5,9)
mydict results can be:
(3,4)
(1,2)
(5,9) or (3,4)
(5,9)
(1,2) etc.. the order will be randomly changed but the values are going to be matched.

```
foreach (var item in myDict.Keys)
{
    int myValue = myDict[item];
    for (int i=0; i<test.Count; i++) // not sure about these nesting loops.
    {
        int pairValue = pairs[i].value
        Assert.AreEqual(myValue, pairValue); // How to do this part for randomly generated values?
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you want to unit test? How myDict, and pairs are on initialized and populated ?

Comment: That's what the key is for. So you can pull the value you are interested on.

Comment: Loop the array, then get the dictionary value.

Comment: `Assert.IsTrue(myDict.OrderBy(d => d.Key).SequenceEqual(expected))`?